# Run a jupyter notebook from another notebook and accept notebook parameters

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I know that we can call one notebook from another using `%run <jupyter-notebook>`

But is there a way to pass in a string parameter while calling a notebook this way? Or any other way to share information from caller notebook to callee notebook?

I tried executing the following:

`%run /root/notebook.ipynb "/root/abc.csv"`

inside the notebook, I print `sys.argv` and I see this on console:

`['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-fa157ce3-83be-4e70-bf95-fe7f83530d4d.json']`

I was expecting to see my argument `/root/abc.csv` in the output for sys.argv according to the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). I may be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using **papermill** python library to do this.

**Syntax**:

```
import papermill as pm
pm.execute_notebook('input.ipynb', 'output.ipynb', {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': ['value2', 'value3']})
```